# Error on creating cassandra cluster with ccm (Cassandra Cluster Manager )

Tags: linux, cassandra, debian, cassandra-2.0

I am trying to follow tutorials on Cassandra academy and this is what I get when trying to run ccm to create a Cassandra cluster.

```
~/cassandra$ ccm create demo_1node -v 2.2.0 -n 1 -s -d
Downloading http://archive.apache.org/dist/cassandra/2.2.0/apache-cassandra-2.2.0-src.tar.gz to /tmp/ccm-RlxXjd.tar.gz (21.283MB)
  22316682  [100.00%]
Extracting /tmp/ccm-RlxXjd.tar.gz as version 2.2.0 ...
Compiling Cassandra 2.2.0 ...
Deleted /home/adelin/.ccm/repository/2.2.0 due to error
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/ccm", line 4, in <module>
    __import__('pkg_resources').run_script('ccm==2.0.4.1', 'ccm')
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 534, in run_script
    self.require(requires)[0].run_script(script_name, ns)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 1445, in run_script
    exec(script_code, namespace, namespace)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ccm-2.0.4.1-py2.7.egg/EGG-INFO/scripts/ccm", line 72, in <module>

  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/ccmlib/cmds/cluster_cmds.py", line 130, in run
  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/ccmlib/cluster.py", line 56, in __init__
  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/ccmlib/cluster.py", line 69, in load_from_repository
  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/ccmlib/repository.py", line 44, in setup
  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/ccmlib/repository.py", line 231, in download_version
ccmlib.common.CCMError: Error compiling Cassandra. See /home/adelin/.ccm/repository/last.log for details


adelin@sofiaag:~/cassandra$ java -version
java version "1.7.0_60"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_60-b19)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.60-b09, mixed mode)


adelin@sofiaag:~/cassandra$ ant -version
Apache Ant(TM) version 1.9.5 compiled on May 31 2015
```

Operating System

```
PRETTY_NAME="Debian GNU/Linux 8 (jessie)"
NAME="Debian GNU/Linux"
VERSION_ID="8"
VERSION="8 (jessie)"
ID=debian
HOME_URL="http://www.debian.org/"
SUPPORT_URL="http://www.debian.org/support/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.debian.org/"
```

here is the error file last.log
https://gist.github.com/AdelinGhanaem/a30e29e1fec9f520d747

Answer (score 1):

Cassandra 2.2 requires Java 8. Update your path and try to launch the command again.

Comment: seems a reasonable I will do so and will come back with results :)

Comment: I've changed the java version to 1.8 but still doesn't work, here is the error file
https://gist.github.com/AdelinGhanaem/593d1c8a63857113d0a7

Comment: http://mradelin.blogspot.com/2015/07/error-packaging-cassandra-220-db-source_31.html this is what I've done when needed to compile cassandra !

Comment: It also says that Cassandra 2.2.0 requires java >= 1.7 https://github.com/apache/cassandra/tree/cassandra-2.2

Comment: Strange, it worked for me. Maybe you had some corrupt JARs remaining from a previous attempt. Next time try deleting `.ccm/repository/${VERSION?}` manually before retrying.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I've done to overcome the problem for now

http://mradelin.blogspot.com/2015/08/fix-error-ccm-cassandra-cluster-manager.html